# How can I get the error returned by the subprocess.check_output() function?

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, subprocess, error-logging

```
#!/bin/python
import subprocess
import traceback
import logging
output_file = "/Users/abhabhin/Desktop/Cisco/Cisco_Tasks/1_KnowledgeTraining/CodeImplementations/report.log"
cmd = "/Users/abhabhin/Desktop/Cisco/Cisco_Tasks/1_KnowledgeTraining/CodeImplementations/script.sh HelloWorld"
try:
    with open(output_file, "w") as file:
        output = (subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True))
        file.write(output.decode())
except Exception as e:
    #logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
    #print("traceback.format_exc() = " + (str)(traceback.format_exc()))
    print("Inside Exception")
    with open(output_file, "w") as file:
        file.write((str)(traceback.format_exc()))
```

Above is my code in which -

"output_file" is the logfile where the output of the command run via check_output is to be stored
"cmd" is the cmd to be run in which a script.sh is run by passing the HelloWorld file.

Now when there is no error on running the command (cmd) via subprocess.check_output() function, the output_file have the content of the cmd output.

But when the the cmd is run via subprocess.check_output() and there is syntactical error in the build.sh which throws an error on console but the error is not logged/written to the output_file.

Please suggest me a way so that I can write the output_file with the console error too.

I cannot use subprocess.run(), so please suggest a way by only using subprocess.check_output()

Refer above code for reference.

Thanks,
Abhinav

Answer (score 0):

By default, you are only capturing standard output. The error will be on standard error.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
To also capture standard error in the result, use stderr=subprocess.STDOUT:

>>>
>>> subprocess.check_output(
...     "ls non_existent_file; exit 0",
...     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
...     shell=True)
'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'
```